# Quickly check for subdirectories in list

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-3.6, os.path, pathlib

I have two sets of paths, with maybe 5000 files in the first set and 10000 files in the second. The first set is contained in the second set. I need to check if any of the entries in the second set is a child of any entry in the first set (i.e. if it's a subdirectory or file in another directory from the first set). There are some additional requirements:

- No operations on the file system, it should be done only on the path strings (except for dealing with symlinks if needed).
- Platform independent (e.g. upper/lower case, different separators)
- It should be robust with respect to different ways of expressing the same path.
- It should deal with both symlinks and their targets.
- Some paths will be absolute and some relative.
- This should be as fast as possible!

I'm thinking along the lines of getting both `os.path.abspath()` and `os.path.realpath()` for each entry and then comparing them with `os.path.commonpath([parent]) == os.path.commonpath([parent, child])`. I can't come up with a good way of running this fast though. Or is it safe to just compare the strings directly? That would make it much much easier. Thanks!

EDIT: I was a bit unclear about the platform independence. It should work for all platforms, but there won't be for example Windows and Unix style paths mixed.

Comment: look into `pathlib`

Comment: I have, but I haven't found any magic bullet there :)

Comment: If some paths are absolute and some are relative, you can’t compare them without using a system call to calculate the full path with `os.path.abspath`.

Comment: I'm fine with making a call to `os.getcwd()`, what I want to avoid is looking at very many files on a distributed file system, since it will be slow.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to speak about `os.path.realpath` which resolves symlinks.

Comment: True, I edited the original post about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can first calculate the real path of all paths using `os.path.realpath` and then use `os.path.commonprefix` to check if one path in a child of the first set of paths.

Example:

```
import os

first = ['a', 'b/x', '/r/c']
second = ['e', 'b/x/t', 'f']

first = set(os.path.realpath(p) for p in first)
second = set(os.path.realpath(p) for p in second)

for s in second:
    if any(os.path.commonprefix([s, f]) == f
           for f in first):
        print(s)
```

You get:

```
/full/path/to/b/x/t
```

Comment: That scales quadratically, so it gets too slow for many files. In my example that would be 5000 * 10000 = 50 million checks.

Comment: Also, if it were enough to check for common prefix then you could get a sorted list from the set and then iterate over that and check if `i` is a parent of `i+1`.

Comment: @Rasmus But how long do the 50 million checks take?